# Why can't I get the correct value of structure pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, dereference

I would like to use the ptr[1]->ReadLength in the function, but it always display 0.

What the method to solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
struct cache_read_block
{
    unsigned short ReadLength;    // How many words
};
typedef struct cache_read_block CACHE_READ_BLOCK;

void getValue(CACHE_READ_BLOCK (*ptr)[100])
{
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[0]->ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[1]->ReadLength);
}

int main(void) {

CACHE_READ_BLOCK arr[100] = {0};

 arr[0].ReadLength = 10;
 arr[1].ReadLength = 5;

 getValue(&arr);

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this function

```
void getValue(CACHE_READ_BLOCK (*ptr)[100])
{
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[0]->ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[1]->ReadLength);
}
```

the parametr is a pointer to an array of 100 elements of the type `CACHE_READ_BLOCK` . You have to derefernce the pointer at first.

```
void getValue(CACHE_READ_BLOCK (*ptr)[100])
{
    printf("index %d\n", ( *ptr )[0].ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ( *ptr )[1].ReadLength);
}
```

It would be simpler to declare and define the function the following way

```
void getValue( CACHE_READ_BLOCK *ptr )
{
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[0].ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[1].ReadLength);
}
```

and call it like

```
getValue( arr );
```

An array used as an argument of a function is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Or as the elements of the array are not changed then the parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

```
void getValue( const vCACHE_READ_BLOCK *ptr )
{
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[0].ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[1].ReadLength);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
void getValue(CACHE_READ_BLOCK (*ptr)[100])
{
    printf("index %d\n", (*ptr)[0].ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", (*ptr)[1].ReadLength);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct cache_read_block
{
    unsigned short ReadLength;    // How many words
};
typedef struct cache_read_block CACHE_READ_BLOCK;

void getValue(CACHE_READ_BLOCK *ptr)
{
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[0].ReadLength);
    printf("index %d\n", ptr[1].ReadLength);
}

int main(void) {

CACHE_READ_BLOCK arr[100] = {0};

 arr[0].ReadLength = 10;
 arr[1].ReadLength = 5;

 getValue(&arr);

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer should explain what you changed and why -- code-only answers are discouraged